# Google+ account authentication error

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-plus

So I'm trying to add google+ account authentication for my web app (using OAuth 2.0).
The button appears and a window pops up on click ("Error: origin_mismatch"), and the console logs "immediate_failed". I've been looking through some similar questions and it seems that the problem is my OAuth javascript origin/redirect URI.

Let's say the sign in page is at: https://www.site.com/path/main.html , so what should be entered in for the redirect URIs and javascript origins?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.site.com for the Javascript origin - if you're using the Javascript flow then the oauth callback doesn't really matter (its used for the server redirect based flow).

Comment: Is the page public? Can you paste the URL that has the sign in button?

Comment: Www.isaacmoldofsky.com/LitCenter/main.html

Comment: Origins are https:www.isaacmoldofsky.com

Comment: The scheme matters - so https:// != http://. You have setup https:// as an origin, but are accessing it on https://. Add http://www.isaacmoldofsky.com to your origins and it should be good.

Comment: Google cloud console requires me to have http:// at the beginning of the URL, so it won't let me do that.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that is stackoverflow being unhelpful and hiding the http:// - i did put that in. please include it!